# Access 2000 regular expressions

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I am getting an error in Access 2000 when using custom functions in VBA and regular expressions ?

The function works 99% of the time, but when the field is `null("")` I get the word `#Error` in the field ?

Here is my expression:

```
(MACHINEO?N?:?\s?\s?""?""?[0-9A-Z_\.-]+)")
```

The function:

```
Public Function parse(record As String, pattern As String) As String
    Set parseRegExp = New RegExp
        parseRegExp.pattern = pattern
        parseRegExp.Global = True

        Dim parseIT As MatchCollection
        Set parseIT = parseRegExp.Execute(record)

        For Each parseReturn In parseIT
            parse = parseReturn
        Next parseReturn
End Function
```

Comment: What is that last `)` for, it doesn't have an opening one ?

Comment: Can you show us that function too ?

Comment: Machine: parse([machine:],"(MACHINEO?N?:?\s?\s?""?""?[0-9A-Z_\.-]+)")  Sorry left the ") at the end on by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use function like this:

```
parse(NZ(record," "), pattern)
```